# Может стоит убрать кнопки "поднять репутацию" для своих вопросов-ответов?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, дизайн

Сделать это так же как и комментариями. А то поднять/опустить нельзя, а кнопки есть. Не то что бы это мешает (это вообще не заметно), но наверное лучше если бы их вообще не было?

Comment: Связанный посты на SE по теме https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52595 и https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12599

Comment: Для тех кому лень идти по ссылкам: предложение еще Этвуд отклонил, в 2010 году н.э. В вопросе на головной Мете выложили скрипт для тех у кого идиосинкразия на ненужные стрелочки.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Убирать не надо, а то не органично будет смотреться.

А вот почему их не залочили - это вот интересный вопрос. Немного изменить цвет, чтоб было очевидно, что элементы не активны и залочить. Если уж боятся, что люди могут не понять, почему элементы не активны, то можно хинт при наведении сделать.

На MSE задал вопрос про это: [Disable up/down vote arrows on your own posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314607/260198)

Answer (score 6):

Не надо, потому что сообщения без стрелочек выглядят странно. Гораздо лучше, когда сайт единообразен. Я бы и на заблокированных стрелочки вернул.

Comment: Единобезобразен. Вполне можно было бы оставить кнопки, но сделать их не кликабельными вовсе. С выводом правильного хинта. Или даже чуть стиль подправить. А то непонятно сразу, зашёл на страницу сокпапетом или нормальным аккаунтом :)

Comment: @alexolut так они же для этого сделали возможность закреплять верхний бар =)  (чтобы сразу видеть сокпапет ты или юзверь дрожащая)